# Tableau percentile calculation

Tags: tableau-api, percentile

I would like to know if the Percentile function in Tableau includes or excludes NULL, or rather, NA values from the calculation. If it includes the NA values, I would like to know how to write the function myself to exclude the NA values. I am new to Tableau, so I appreciate any help.
Thanks!
ACE

Comment: I would also like to know how Tableau handles ties and whether I can change the method easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau excludes NULL for Percentile function.